# How to test webservice connection

Tags: java, javascript, android, ios, cordova

I develop a android and a iOS phonegapp app.
The native android code load the html file for the app with:

```
super.loadUrl()
```

In this html file I start ajax requests to a webservice.

But before i connect to the webservice and do ajax calls i would test the connection to the webservice and when I can't connect to the webservice, the app should be close before i load the html, with a alert or warning.

Comment: how about sending the ajax request after loading phonegap. Till that you can give a loading screen/ splash screen. And If you cant connect to webservice you can call custom exit code.

Comment: Test your web service response using Junit now...http://findnerd.com/list/view/Testing-Web-Service-response-using-Junit-in-Android/3193/

Answer (score 0):

You can use an HttpURLConnection to send a request and check the response body for text that is unique to that page (rather than just checking to see if there's a response at all, just in case an error or maintenance page or something is being served).

Apache Commons has a library that removes a lot of the boiler plate of making Http requests in Java.

I've never done anything like this specifically on Android, but I'd be surprised if it's any different.

Here's a quick example:

```
URL url = new URL(URL_TO_APPLICATION);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stream); // You can read the stream however you want. Scanner was just an easy example
boolean found = false;
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    String next = scanner.next();
    if(TOKEN.equals(next)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(found) {
    doSomethingAwesome();
} else {
    throw aFit();
}
```

Also try out this

He probably needs Java code since he's working on Android. The Java equivalent -- which I believe works on Android -- should be:

```
InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut)
```

Comment: but this let you know only if any connection is available, and not if the web server is ready / if server is up

Comment: i need to know if the server is online or not.